# Is there a way to detect when my computer plugs into a dock in Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, dock

I am trying to run a .PS1 script on my Windows 11 Surface device every time the computer connects to a Surface Dock. I am attempting to figure out if I can use Task Scheduler to detect an event every time the Dock connects, but I can't seem to figure out which event it is (or if this is the wrong way to do this).

Any advice you have would be very welcome!

I tried going through the Event Monitor to find events for the connection of the Dock or something else that also connects at the same time (like a USB device), but I can't quite figure it out

Comment: You should probably write an event handler rather than trying to use the task scheduler for something that doesn't happen on a schedule.

Comment: Nothing happens in the System event log when you plug or unplug the dock ?